# how to remove extension in php

Tags: php, .htaccess, php-extension

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /online_shoping/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

this is my code for removing .php extension after use .php removed but ? and = still appear and also my login script failed after use this code so please guide me where m wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

use this it works for me

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
# IF the request filename with .php extension is a file which exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
# AND the request is not for a directory
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]
# redirect to the php script with the requested filename
```

Comment: But its not working for me

Comment: do you use ajax in login script?

Comment: No its only Javascript

Comment: in your script remove php extention. for example if you have `<form name="myform" action="check.php" method="post">` must be change to `<form name="myform" action="check" method="post">`

Comment: Thanks for help but if i used Header Location Method in php for redirect then can i also remove .php there?

Comment: you can test it. but in ajax call when i remove php extention it works fine.

Comment: ya its working thank u so much, also can u suggest me how to replace ? = with /

Comment: saerch this site probably found it